# Chrome not firing by default through the webdriver-manager

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing

I'm a newbie in e2e tests with protractor and I've recently encountered an issue. When I try to run my test (which is basically the same one I found on the official protractor website), the server starts by using Firefox as a default browser. As I read, chrome supposed to be the one used by default.

```
16:17:24.345 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=firefox}]])
16:17:24.345 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=firefox}]
16:17:27.305 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{count=1, browserName=firefox}]]
```

Due to the Firefox issue [#1734](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1734), the test fails all the time

```
Failures:

  1) angularjs homepage todo list should add a todo
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 36000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 36.777 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure
```

So I added chrome as another browser to use into the configuration file

**conf.js**

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',      
  capabilities: {
   browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
  framework: 'jasmine'
};
```

Here's the test

**todo-spec.js**

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('http://angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoText')).sendKeys('write a protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write a protractor test');
  });
});
```

But it still does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you have `chromedriver` in your path? Otherwise you would need to provide `chromeDriver: './selenium/chromedriver'` in config object. However this still doesn't explain why Firefox is being launched instead of chrome

Comment: Do you have any interesting environment variables set?  I believe protractor/webdriver will use some to pick default browsers.

Comment: Yes! You put the finger on it. I forgot to add chrome to the environment variable SELENIUM_BROWSER. It works like a charm now. Thank you P.T.!